# Latex: Showing only few lines in lstlisting

Tags: latex, lstlisting

For displaying only few lines of source code lstlisting has a linerange key which prints only those ranges.

```
\documentclass[slidestop]{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \begin{lstlisting}[language=C,linerange={1-2,5-6}]
    #include<stdio.h>
    int void main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
      printf("hello world\n");
      return 0;
    }
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The above listing displays following lines of code without any spaces in between the lines. :

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int void main(int argc, char **argv)
      return 0;
    }
```

What I really want is

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int void main(int argc, char **argv)


      return 0;
    }
```

I want the lines 3-4 not to be displayed but I need blank lines for that range. So there should be 2 blank lines between first two and last two displayed lines.

Constraints:

- Source code should not be changed, it
  is actually in a separate file which
  can't be changed
- The actual source code I have is
  pretty big so using multiple
  lstlisting for different parts of
  source is cumbersome.

[Update]:
My requirement in short: 
**"lines in source code which are excluded in given range(s) should be printed as blank lines(even when they are non empty in source code)"**

Answer (score 1):

Inserting the following piece of code in the preamble seems to do the trick.

```
\makeatletter
\let\oldMSkipToFirst=\lst@MSkipToFirst
\gdef\lst@MSkipToFirst{\lst@formfeed\oldMSkipToFirst}
\makeatother
```